# I have JSONField use a library to call this object for sql postgres How to use sqlite the same library

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

#### I have JSONField use a library to call this object for sql postgres
How to use sqlite the same library

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
class DeclareResult(models.Model):
    marks = JSONField(blank=True)
```